# git merge branch commited my local changes

Tags: git, git-merge

I have 2 branches, old and new, I made modifications to old and commited, then I moved to new.
Then apparently I moved to the new branch, modified some code and then merged old branch.
And at some point I did push
Now a few months later I noticed origin/new branch has my local changes though I don't remember commiting them.
Could my local changes have been commited by a merge even though I did not commited them explicitly?

The first place where I see the changes is in the merge message.
How can I tell if I actually commited those changes without noticing?
Could a `commit -a` after a merge conflict have commited my local changes too even if I did not modify the file?

Comment: You keep saying "changes". Git does not traffic in changes. It traffics in _commits_. Every commit is a snapshot of the state of all your files as they appear in the index. `git commit -a` updates the index to include the current state of all the files Git knows about and performs the commit.

Comment: The phrase "my local changes too even if I did not modify the file" is very strange. A local change _is_ a modification.

Comment: If the changes are in the repository, they got committed. `git commit -a` will commit all changes to all tracked files; that's what the `-a` is for. This all sounds like you had a messy merge conflict. You can look back through your changes with `git log -p --decorate` to find which commit added your changes.

Comment: @matt Sry did save, didin't commit it, but now people explained commit -a would commit files that had nothing to do with the conficts.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please delete the question.